# Benefits of defining a function accepting short int instead of int

Tags: c, function, int, short

I read here [Benefit of using short instead of int in for... loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270111/benefit-of-using-short-instead-of-int-in-for-loop) that it doesn't really make sense to use short instead of plain int in loop counters because in most architectures short will occupy the same amount of memory space as int. That makes me think that short ints are really not useful because they don't result in what one might expect, that is saving memory. However, in production code I often see that short ints are used as function arguments. For example, when I was browsing coreboot (coreboot.org) using ack-grep I found many functions that take short. I realize that coreboot code is rather low-level but I wonder what is the benefit, if any, of using short instead of int in C on x86 architecture? When should I use it?

Comment: The biggest benefit to using `short` comes when they're used in aggregate -- in an array of `short` IOW -- as that array takes up half the space of an array of `int`.  The other possible benefit is that if the function is defined to take a `short`, you know that the value will be in the range -32768..+32767 (on systems with 2's complement integers and 16-bit `short`, which is most systems), which may simplify your validation processes inside the function.  Otherwise, variables of type `short` aren't of a lot of help unless you're matching an external specification of some sort.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why not make this an answer?

Comment: By `validation process' - do you mean checking for overflow? How would short make that easier?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest benefit to using `short` comes when they're used in aggregate — primarily in an array of `short` IOW, or possibly as members of a structure ‐ as an array of `short` normally takes up half the space of an array of `int` with the same number of entries.

The other possible benefit is that if the function is defined to take a `short`, you know that the value will be in the range -32768..+32767 (on systems with 2's complement integers and 16-bit `short`, which is most systems), which may simplify your validation processes inside the function.  If the type passed were `int` instead of `short` but the range of valid values is -32788..+32767, then you would have to validate that the passed value was in range (assuming `sizeof(int) > sizeof(short)`, which is not guaranteed but is typical).

Otherwise, variables of type `short` aren't a lot of help unless you're matching an external specification of some sort.

Comment: +1 for not saying sizeof(int) is always > sizeof(short).  Embedded systems today are a notable use where they are often the same.

Answer (score 1):

Some functions are meant for `short` and others for `int`.

If one wanted to count all the bits set in a `short` one would use

```
int CountBits_short(short x);
```

If one wanted to count all the bits set in a `int` one would use

```
int CountBits_int(int x);
```

There is not performance issue here, just a functional difference.

---

@JonathanLeffler comment to the OP sums up *the* most useful reason for `short` in they may take up less space.

---

Other

Other thoughts:

On platforms where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(short)` there is no performance benefit.
Otherwise we know `sizeof(int) > sizeof(short)`.

The compiler may make similar entry/exit code for the following and no performance difference.

```
void foo_s(short bar);
void foo_i(int bar);
```

In passing pointer as in

```
void foo_s(short *bar);
void foo_i(int *bar);
```

The `sizeof(bar)` is the same, for it is an address, again no benefit in augment passing.

In passing arrays as in

```
void foo_s(short bar[]);
void foo_i(int bar[]);
```

`bar` becomes the address of the first element, again the same size, for it is an address, again no benefit in augment passing.

Performance of functions that use `short` are nominally thought to be slightly worse than `int` in that various amounts of code may be needed to promote / demote between `short` and the processor's preferred `int`.   `int` by definition *1 is the processor's nominally preferred integer size.

Of course any performance issues need profiling to validate, but the gist is that `short` is used to save space at a potential nominal cost in performance.

*1 still looking for spec def, so for now this is my opinion.