# password_verify not returning true/false

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with trying to login using the saved hash from my database, I save my password the following way, which works fine:

```
adduser($conn, '3', $username, $password);
```

This calls the following function:

```
  function adduser ($conn, $level, $username, $password)
  {
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
  $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  $user = "INSERT INTO users (level, username, password)
  VALUES ('$level', '$username', '$password')";
  mysqli_query($conn, $user) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
  }
```

My password field is a `CHAR(60)` so the stored password hash should be the right size.

When I try to login I call this function:

```
if (login($conn, $username, $password) === true){

}
```

Which exists here:

```
  function login ($conn, $username, $password)
  {
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
$query = "SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$hash = $row["password"];
$verify = password_verify($password, $hash);
if ($verify)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
  }
```

My issue is that it never returns true or false, which makes it impossible for me to login...

Extra:
It succesfully post to database

I also tried running this, which succesfully posted the data from my database

```
$query = "SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row["password"];
```

Update

---

Doing this:

```
echo '<br/>';
echo $hash;
echo '<br/>';
echo $password;
```

Gives me the following output:

```
$2y$10$OfJhVve4GMZRfjfelb8sNOJ7EN5NAAGOmsN6OS/SC7PZGU5mDNOou
hej
```

Which matches the password in my database

```
$2y$10$OfJhVve4GMZRfjfelb8sNOJ7EN5NAAGOmsN6OS/SC7PZGU5mDNOou
```

Comment: side note: you shouldn't escape a password/hash function, passwords such as `123'\abc<` are perfectly valid and will be modified on insertion.

Comment: `My issue is that it never returns true or false` wrong, on an `if()else{}` one case will always return something (no madder what `$verfiy` holds). So you are making elsewhere something wrong. And your statement is false.

Comment: I'd sure like to know what the variables' values are and their origins.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the $password is the user input, while the $hash is the one from the db

Comment: tell me; what's the value of the password in question in that said row? a hash or a plain text password? do a var dump

Comment: @Fred-ii- the value of $password is in this case "test" and the value of $hash (the password from database) is indeed a hash

Comment: @guitarherokk what the matter ?

Comment: I edited my post to show the outputs of the $password and $hash

Comment: @guitarherokk What is that 'hej' after hash?

Comment: Thats the user inputted password which I use to match against the hashed password

Comment: @guitarherokk can you check hash password before inserting and verify with  both displaying password

Comment: also i have doubt about char(60) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793298/php-password-hash-maximum-password-length check it

Comment: @guitarherokk You've my answer below.

Comment: @AhmedGinani The length of the hashed password is 60, the length of the password column was 60, bumped it up to 72, and suddenly things work, before the length was 254, and it didnt work. Makes no sense to me.. But it is working now that I changed the length... Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Glad it worked. You can also visit : http://stackoverflow.com/tour to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing your entire code, I have come to the following conclusion.

The problem here is that you are escaping the password while inserting it into your database, which is something I did raise in comments from the beginning.

> *"side note: you shouldn't escape a password/hash function, passwords such as `123'\abc<` are perfectly valid and will be modified on insertion."*

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
```

Side note for ^ - Consult Edit #2 below, near *"However..."*:

Simply don't use it, just keep/use the assignment normally.

Both `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` do their job, so there's no need to escape passwords.

You will need to remove it from the code that you used to insert it into the database with, and start over again with a new set of hashes.

That escaping function is most likely adding a character during insertion.

Side note: Just for the record, my password column is `VARCHAR`, yet that shoulnd't be a difference from your `CHAR` (Edit: consult footnote). If it is then ALTER your column to be `VARCHAR`.

The manual on `password_hash()` though, suggests using 255 for a length, being a good bet.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

---

Edit footnote:

As per a comment I posted beneath my answer.

It looks to have a difference. This Q&A [What's the difference between VARCHAR and CHAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885630/1415724) shows it, as per the accepted answer

VARCHAR is variable-length.

CHAR is fixed length.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885635/1415724

---

**Edit #2:**

After further testing to see if it made a difference by ALTER'ing the password column from `VARCHAR(255)` to `CHAR(60)` made a difference; it did not.

Tests performed:

- Inserted a new hash without the escaping function and verifying: `TRUE`.
- Inserted a new hash with the escaping function and verifying: `FALSE`.

Therefore and as I stated originally; the fault lies with the use of `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

However and going over your code again, this line:

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
```

You were using the `$username` variable here which also accounts for the wrong value being inserted in the database. All of these put together were the problems from the get go.

Comment: This might aswell be a solution, though I figured changing the length to 72 in the password field, also did the trick without removing the escapes. But thank you for pointing out how it works, I'll make sure to remove it

Comment: @guitarherokk Even if you increase the lengh; the initial problem is still there and you need to start over by clearing all your hashes and create new ones. This was the case for me; when I escaped the password, it rendered as FALSE. Removing it rendered it as TRUE.

Comment: Thank you really appreciate with you and next time i will take care about it

Comment: Indeed, not sure if the difference is in the VARCHAR and CHAR, perhaps that has to do with it too? Already cleared the hashes, and removed the escapes. But I was able to make it render as TRUE while using the escapes

Comment: @guitarherokk It looks to have a difference. This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/1885630/1415724 shows it, as per the accepted answer *"VARCHAR is variable-length.

CHAR is fixed length."* http://stackoverflow.com/a/1885635/1415724

Comment: @guitarherokk *"but I was able to make it render as TRUE while using the escapes"* - Again;  don't escape passwords. If and when someone later on decides to use apostrophes or other characters that an escaping function will interpret as being a possible SQL injection, the login will fail on `password_verify()` since and for example: `123'hello` will be technically be modified/inserted as `123\'abc` in and embedded in the hash; don't do that.

Comment: can the downvoter please explain their downvote? I would like to know and if I made an error or a misconception about something so I can fix it.

Comment: @guitarherokk I made a few more edits to my answer and I would like you to reload it and see them further below from my original post. There were a few things happening in there that you were not aware of, including myself till I went over your code again.

Comment: @Bsienn I felt that I had to further test this and to improve my answer in order to show the OP and future visitors what was going on in there. *Cheers*