# BCrypt vs PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1

Tags: java, security, bcrypt, pbkdf2, jbcrypt

In order to hash passwords securely, which algorithm should I use? `BCrypt` or `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1`?

Which is more secure? `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` is built into Java while `BCrypt` is available via [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) library (which has mostly received positive reviews).

Also if I go with `BCrypt` should I limit my user's password entry to 55 characters only (since that is the limit of `BCrypt`)?

It would be helpful if you are `Java` specific.
Do note that I would go for the option that makes the passwords more secure and brute-forcing more difficult.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, both are equally secure. I'd go with BCrypt.

Comment: See this answer on Security.stackexchange.com: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/2019

Comment: On the other hand here ( https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3725723 ) you will find a couple of valid points towards bcrypt (or against pbkdf2 if you prefer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not the same, and they are not equally secure.

On a CPU, they both use about the same amount of resources, and are about the same at defending the password.

The issue comes down to GPU based attacks. Due to the architectures of GPUs, bcrypt is actually harder to run than SHA1 (or SHA256). Therefore, it's easier to parallelize PBKDF2 + sha1 than it is bcrypt.

To put some actual numbers on it, we'll draw from [This presentation](http://passwords12.at.ifi.uio.no/Jeremi_Gosney_Password_Cracking_HPC_Passwords12.pdf).

Sha-1 is about 3x more expensive than md5. So if we look at the slow hashing function slides, we can conclude that md5crypt is about 3x faster than pbkdf2-sha1. That's quite a bit of guesswork, but it's in the margin of what we're looking for.

So that means, that for an equavilent CPU runtime, we can expect PBKDF2-sha1 to run about 25 Million hashes per second on the GPU cluster. Compare that to BCrypt (with cost 5) which runs at 75 Thousand hashes per second.

So that implies that PBKDF2+sha1 is about 1000 times weaker than bcrypt at equivalent cost settings.

Note though that PBDFK2+sha512 is almost as slow as bcrypt. This has to do with SHA-512 using 64 bit operations (which aren't native in today's GPUs).

So in short, bcrypt is orders of magnitude more secure than PBKDF2+SHA1. It's more secure than PBKDF2+SHA512, but not by as much of a margin.

And this relies on GPU architecture of today. In the future, if cache sizes and instruction sets change significantly, these differences could wash out. And that's why newer algorithms like scrypt exist.

So just use bcrypt. [And don't worry about the character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594613/how-to-hash-long-passwords-72-characters-with-blowfish/16597402#16597402)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What I would like to ask is would it not give users (specifically those users who use very long passwords with very low entropy) a false sense of security?
`Firstly`, because it does not use all the bits provided by the user.
`Secondly`, because the password could be replaced by any other password with the first 72 characters same. This would mean more than one password for the same user.

I understand that you do not advocate pre-hashing but what do you suggest I should do in this case?

Comment: pre-hashing with sha-256 would reduce the overall entropy. For low-quality-long passwords, this isn't a huge issue. But for complex ones, it's an issue. In practice, it's likely OK to pre-hash, but be sure to use **raw** output (not hex). I just prefer to publicly recommend vetted algorithms rather than composing my own.

Comment: In that case, if I do use SHA-512 to pre-hash (no salt, no pepper) the password, and then pass the raw output to BCrypt (with 12 rounds), is it safe to consider that my passwords will not be broken in the near future?

Comment: Nothing is ever safe. The key is that the amount of work to break all but trivial passwords is so high, that it's not worth it for an attacker to proceed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and helping me so much.

Answer (score 2):

**It doesn't really matter.**

The difference between the security of the two of them is not significant enough to arrive at a meaningful choice. If you are looking for a thorough discussion, though, take a look at both links in Eugene's comments

**What *does* matter is that you them correctly.**

That means:

- Choosing a right cost factor / iteration count. If you are thorough, you will want to benchmark how slow a hash function your servers can tolerate. The slower (=higher cost factor / iteration count) the better. To give you a ballpark number, my full disk encryption software has determined that PBKDF2 with HmacSHA1 needs ~10000 iterations to run 50ms.
- Using salt correctly: Each password needs an accompanying random value (salt), that you store alongside the hash and use as input for each hashing. Don't use the same salt with every password, [that would be pepper](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/password-hashing-add-salt-pepper-or-is-salt-enough) and is nice to have, but no replacement for salt.
- Store your password in an upgradable way. At some time later you might want to change the cost factor or add a pepper value or change the hashing scheme to scrypt, once it is widely accepted. To allow for that, the database entries need to tell which parameter choice were used to generate the password. As an example, see [this commonly used unix passwords storage format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165/371137).

**"Also if I go with BCrypt should I limit my user's password entry to 55 characters only (since that is the limit of BCrypt)?"**

No. Hash the password once with SHA1 or SHA256 and use the output like you would have used the password before. If you want to apply pepper, this is the spot to do it. Finally, if it sounds like to much of a hassle, this might be the deciding factor to use PBKDF2 instead of bcrypt.

Comment: If I use SHA-512 to hash the password once and then pass the raw output (not hex since it reduces entropy) to the BCrypt function, will it be safe to consider that my passwords will not be broken in the near future?